# Get current frame in actionscript. What instance should I refer to?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to actionscript. I'm trying to make a menusystem that will jump to specific frames depending on what frame I'm currently on. I have made a switch/case to evaluate the current frame. I have managed to find this code to get the current frame but I need an instance of my entire flash movie it seems? I have tried this (psudo code sort of).

```
var frame = myClip.currentFrame;
```

I then proceed to test frame in the switch/case statement. (All this is an event for a mouse event listener BTW).

Now how can I refer to myClip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found I could use `this.currentFrame;`, seems obvious right now.

Comment: I think it should be ` this._currentFrame; ` (Flash 5)